# storing user data in firebase with unique identifiers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a publicly accessible app. No sign in is required but I need a way to store user data in the database as an object associated with a unique key.
From what I understand, tokens would be a way to get a unique identifier from firebase(??)
I tried creating an anonymous user and getting a token like this:

```
let user = firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
user.getIdToken(true);
```

I expected `getIdToken` to return a string but I get an object.
So...
1) Are tokens what I want to do this?
2) If so how can I get a new token as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I was trying to set up a binding to sync my app with Firebase, which I just realized I don't need at all! (I just need to push the data at the end of the poll).
Of course as soon as removed that requirement it was as simple as:

```
firebase.database().ref().push().set(myData);
```

When using the `push()` method, Firebase automatically generates a unique key which is all I need...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code as a global listener on ur page to check if the sign-in is successful:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
       // User is signed in.
       var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
       var unique_id = user.uid;

   } else {
       // User is signed out.
       // ...
   }
});
```

This snippet has been taken from the Firebase Anonymous Auth link: [Click Here to open link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)

Comment: Thanks. I did see that snippet. At first I used the uid to record the data but eventually Firebase banned my IP because it was making too many new user requests. Since this app will be in a public space it might be blocked by Firebase again, which is why I was wondering if using tokens would be better...